# reload jqModal content

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I'm having some trouble with the jqModal

This is the code:

```
    $("#usermodal").jqm({ modal: true });

    $("#rommel").on("click", ".modalup", function (e) {
        alert($(this).attr('href'));
        //$("#usermodal").jqmHide();
        $("#usermodal").jqm({ ajax: $(this).attr('href') });
        $("#usermodal").jqmShow();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

The problem is, when the modal is shown, and I click an a.modalup which is inside the modal HTML (so the event fires), the modal does not 'update' its content.
only when I call `$("#usermodal").jqmHide()` and show again, it will be the new page, but that generates flickering...